# Add parentheses under equations?

Tags: amsmath, mathtools

How can I put parentheses under equations like this:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one possibility:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{4}
&Y_t = {}&&\hat{\beta}_0 + {}&&\hat{\beta}_1 X_1 + \dots + {}&&\hat{\beta}_k X_k, \\
&(t)     &&()                && ()                           &&()  
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option using a new command,

```
\newcommand{\stacktwo}[2]{\begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\\#2\end{array}}
```

can be like this:

```
\begin{equation}
\stacktwo{Y_t}{(t)} = \stacktwo{\hat{\beta}_0}{()} + \stacktwo{\hat{\beta}_1}{()} X_1 + \dots + \stacktwo{\hat{\beta}_k}{()} X_k,
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Also, you can load the `stackengine` package and use the command `\stackMath\stackunder{Y_t}{(t)}`, etc. from this package.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\stackMath
\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}
\def\xbeta_#1{\stackunder{\beta_#1}{()}}
\begin{document}
\[
\stackunder{Y_t}{(t)} = \xbeta_0 + \xbeta_1 X_1 + \dots + \xbeta_k X_k, 
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I added a `stackengine` example.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that uses the `\underset` macro of the `amsmath` package. In the following screenshot, the parenthetic material is centered below the corresponding `\beta` particles (pun intended) in the preceding row. Simply adjust the closing curly braces if the parenthetic material should be centered on `\beta_i X_`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\under[2]{\underset{\mathclap{\textstyle(#1)}}{#2}}
\begin{document}
\[
\under{t}{Y_t} =  \under{u}{\hat{\beta}_0} 
                + \under{v}{\hat{\beta}_1} X_1  
                + \dots 
                + \under{wxyz}{\hat{\beta}_k} X_k
\]
\end{document}
```